# How to keep track of global mouse position in Angular?

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Have a slightly weird one for you... I have a site I'm working on where I need to manipulate a really giant hairy arm used as a cursor. The site has multiple routes and the giant hand cursor is only present on one of the routes. I have a directive that manipulates the absolute positioning of the hand. The rest of the site is all Angular, so I feel a bit guilty going the jquery route currently in the directive as seen below.

```
<div id="big-cursor" big-hand><img src="images/hand2.png" /></div>
```

and

```
angular.module('variousAssetsApp').directive('bigHand', function () {

    var link = function($scope, element){

        $("html,body").mousemove(function(e) {
           var tarX = e.pageX;
           var tarY = e.pageY;
           element.css({
               top: tarY + 20,
               left : tarX + 20
           },0);
        });
    }


    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };
});
```

The issue is that I need this hand cursor to be at the right position when coming in off a different route. Right now, it is only in the right position once the mouse is moved AFTER coming to the route (since the directive `link` function is executed only there), so there is an immediate jump in the hand/arm from one position to the other.

Are there any better solutions to this? The only thing I can think is to create a factory that holds the current position, but that seems like it would get called too much and too fast. I can't put the cursor outside of it's current route as I've got some pretty heavy `z-index` stuff going on as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem: when the directive is instantiated, no mousemove event is fired (the cursor hasn't moved yet), so it cannot position the bigHand until the cursor moves.

So, you do have to keep track of the mouse position throughout your site.

I would add a simple directive to your document body which keeps track of the coordinates. It could be paired with a service to hold the x and y values. The bigHand directive could then watch those values from the service and reposition the hand image accordingly.

Comment: Makes sense, but wouldn't that create a huge overload with the service being called every movement?

Comment: Ok, I'm getting a 10 $digest iterations reached. Aborting! error when I'm running a $watch on this service. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: nevermind, sorry. I only need to call the service once on route change. :)